# Friction-normal forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, vectors

Is friction always perpendicular to normal force? I think so because friction is always parallel to the surfaces in contact and direction of normal force will be along the common normal of the 2 surfaces in contact at the point of contact. I am still not sure, can anyone help me?

Comment: Why would you not think so?

Comment: I’m voting to close your question if you can’t tell me why would you not think so. It is likely others will do the same

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the origin of the normal force and friction are the same(electromagnetic force between two surface in contact). You can imagine this as two bunches of particles(of the two surface) attracting while repulsing each other in whatever direction. So... it's really hard to say which force is exactly causing resistance to the moving object or which force is "supporting" the object. So people categorize(decompose) all forces into two sets, one normal to the surface and one against the moving direction of the object. Regardless of the shape, the roughness of the surface or the moving pattern of the object(bouncing or sliding etc.), friction is always perpendicular to the normal by definition.